# MySQLが起動出来ない

Tags: mysql, macos

MySQLを起動するため`$ mysql.server start`と実行しても

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/<マック名>.pid).
```

というエラーが出て出来ない。

ログを見ると `Permission denied` と記録されていたので、

```
sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/var/mysql
```

で権限をmysqlにしても結果は一緒だった。

とりあえずググって出るやつは一通り試しました。

#### 追記

ログのエラー↓

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.21/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/var/mysql/<マック名>.local.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.21/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/var/mysql/<マック名>.local.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.21/bin/mysqld_safe: line 198: /usr/local/var/mysql/<マック名>.local.err: Permission denied
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.21/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /usr/local/var/mysql/<マック名>.local.err: Permission denied
```

Comment: `sudo mysql.server start` はどうなりますか？ また、ログの該当箇所を質問に含めると回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: 結果は一緒で、ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/<マック名>.pid)でした

Comment: `chown`で指定しているユーザ・グループ名はアンダバー付きであっていますか？（システムに存在するユーザ・グループなのでしょうか）。また、エラーに出ている`*.pid`を削除してみるとどうなりますか。

Comment: 当該.pidファイルおよび、その格納ディレクトリのオーナー、グループ、パーミッションを追記してください。

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL起動できなくなった　The server quit without updating PID file](https://qiita.com/yuki0208/items/1d5554d98e9ec76084bd)　に書かれている方法は試されましたか？

Answer (score 0):

1. 一旦 `chmod 777 /usr/local/var/mysql` として、起動する。
2. 起動したらファイルのオーナーを確認
3. 2の情報を元に対処。1も元に戻す。

これでダメなら分かりません。